# Can't do modifications in .bash_profile

Tags: bash

I am not sure what happened but I can't add anything in my `.bash_profile` on `mac`, unless I use `sudo` command, while before it was working even without this.

I tried `sudo chmod 755 .bash_profile`, but I still can't do anything without sudo. Does anyone know what happened and how can I go back? This is the message I get using emacs: `Buffer is read-only: #<buffer .bash_profile>`.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la .bash_profile`?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  485 Aug 24 11:31 .bash_profile

Comment: You want to run `sudo chown your_username .bash_profile`. Looks like root owns that file for some reason right now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.